# Increase the height of wrapper based on the size of ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a template in master page in asp.net and I use ContentPlaceHolder.

The issue I'm facing is if the ContentPlaceHolder is larger than the wrapper, then the information displayed in ContentPlaceHolder is hidden behind the footer.

As you can see in this image, the white space is the wrapper. and the TABS end line is behind the footer image.  But if you look at the second image (where info is displayed within the wrapper) everything looks normal.

[image]

[image]

Here's the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #FFFFFF
}
```

Here's the asp.net code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page" class="container">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                       <p>
                           &nbsp;</p>
                       <p>
                           <br />
                       </p>
                       <p>
                       </p>
                       <p>
                       </p>
                       <p>
                       </p>
                       <p>
                       </p>
                       <p>
                       </p>
                       <p>
                       </p>
                   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #content -->
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

and here's the css for container:

```
.container {
width: 999px;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 256px;
}
```

How can I increase the wrapper so if the data in ContentPlaceHolder is larger it increases the height of the wrapper?

I tried to set the

```
height: auto;
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my issue:

```
<div id="page" class="container" style ="height: auto;">
```